# Removing last added Marker with number on .title

Tags: java, android

I immediately want to point out that I know such methods as setVisible () and remove (), but I do not know how to use them in this particular case. Well, in my application I add markers on the map in different places, which are numbered .titles and would like to make a button that will remove the last added marker.
Each successive marker in my application has a feature .title (String.valueOf (f)), where f is the numbers that represent another marker from 0.
I might add that the markers are assigned to each collected location saved in the ArrayList.
How will look button, which when pressed will remove the last marker from the map? Only last.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hold pointers to them then you will be able to remove them, here is sample:

```
// Somewhere above:
private Marker mMyLocationMarker;

// Add marker with options
mMyLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(options);

// And to remove:
mMyLocationMarker.remove();
```

need more markers? - hold pointers in `List`, etc..

Comment: i think its good idea, but:
currently i have a lot of LatLng in ArrayList, and all LatLng have Markers, and when i do mMyLocationMarker.remove(); all my markers disappear, and i want just only last Marker disappear

Comment: not all markers disappear, my english low, sory
i have different problem, its work for last marker very thank, but when i put 1, 2 and 3 markers, method remove() - remove last, but when i click again i want to remove again and always when i click i want to remove last and last, i hope u understand :)

Comment: get last marker in list, make remove from map, then make remove from list, what is the problem? you can then again get latest from list and repeat ) until list will be empty. Don't be lazy, tons of samples hot to do this on stackoverflow.

Comment: still no work, i have declaration   

 public ArrayList<Marker> listMarker = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    public int p = listMarker.size();
    public Marker singleMarker;
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .visible(true);


        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);

        listMarker.add(p, singleMarker);

Comment: i cant edit comment, its horrible, please check my problem under this post